# react native navigation TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_RNGestureHandlerModule.default.handleSetJSResponder')

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I follow the steps of react-native docs.

```
npx react-native init SelfApp --template react-native-template-typescript
```

and then follow the steps of [react-native-navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtcSO.png).

```
yarn add @react-navigation/native 
yarn add react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
```

then i add code

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
```

to the first line of app.tsx.

then run `yarn start`, I got this error.

[image: error]

i tried a lot of times, but still in trouble, and here is my package.json

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hey according to [this discussion](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/676) on react-native-gesture-handler's GitHub, it's either a problem of linking, if you are on Android or a problem of some pods not being installed if you are on iOS.

It would be helpful to know which version of React Native you are using because if it's >= 60, it should support auto-linking, and if it is < 60, you should link the library manually.

In that last case:
[Try these steps](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/676#issuecomment-510131221)

For iOS:

```
$ cd ios

$ pod install
```

Another possible solution that has worked for other people, according to the discussion I mentioned above (see [this specific response](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/676#issuecomment-605499012)):

```
1 - Delete/Remove your node_modules directory
```

rm -rf node_modules

```
2 - Install your dependencies again
```

If you are using Yarn `$ yarn install`  or if you are using npm `npm install`

```
3 Clean your Gradle

cd android
./gradlew clean
cd ..
react-native run-android
```

Comment: My react-native version is >= 60, and i started with `yarn ios` to start. I have tried `cd  ios && pod install`, But it still shows the error.

Comment: What do you mean by `yarn ios`?